# Access file adjacent to jar file

Tags: java, file, io

How can I access the file adjacent to a jar file (not inside it) in the cleanest way possible?

I've tried various combinations like `File configFile = new File("..//pinger.properties");` and `Pinger.class.getResourceAsStream("pinger.properties");` but the file isn't being read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [java.util.Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

```
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pinger.properties"));
```

Another sample is [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/Props.html).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access the file adjacent to a jar file (not inside it) in the cleanest way possible?

Add a manifest file that references the dependent Jar using a relative path<sup>1</sup>.  Then use `getResource(String)` to get an `URL` to the resource.

1. See [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

**Get the location of your jar file**

Consider the following function

```
public String path(String filename)
{
URL url1 = getClass().getResource("");
String ur=url1.toString();
ur=ur.substring(9);
String truepath[]=ur.split("myjar.jar!");
truepath[0]=truepath[0].replaceAll("%20"," ");
return truepath[0]+filename;
}//This method will work on Windows and Linux as well.
//You can alternatively use the following line to get the path of your jar file
//classname.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Suppose your jar file is in D:\Test\dist

Then path() will return /D:/Test/dist/filename